# Delete third party code module in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Is the `deleteNewModule()` method of `CodeModuleManger` able to delete any third party application cod module?

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine that you'd be able to delete any module on the device. That would allow for so many security holes. What I CAN imagine is that you'd be able to delete any modules that correspond to the current key associated with the current running app. I.E. you can update your own application. Note: I have not tested deleting other apps, however I KNOW you can update your own modules.

Comment: It is possible by taking the handle of that module.. and after getting the handle corrensponding action is performed on that handle..